# jQuery Validation and Form Plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-validate

I have no luck running this both plugin in the same page the 
Form: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/  and  Validation: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

every time I check the error console in firefox it says "jQuery is not defined"

sorry i forgot to add the header.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jqueryValidation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="Data.asp">
<input type="text" name="ISNo" id="ISNo" class="required"/>
<input type="text" name="ISDate" id="ISDate" class="required"/>
<input type="submit" value="save!">
</form>

<form name="Search" id="Search" method="post" action="Search.asp">
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname"/>
<input type="text" name="txtaddress" id="txtaddress"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you a reference on the jquery lib ?

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to load the jQuery plugin scripts before you've loaded jQuery itself - or you're not loading jQuery at all. Solution: your `<head>` should look something like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.validation.js"></script>
</head>
```

N.B. you may also have issues using those plugins with the latest version of jQuery (currently 1.5) since they do not appear to have been tested with versions beyond 1.3.2 (Forms) and 1.4.2 (Validation).

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the head. they are all added but still i cant get them to work.

Comment: @reign: are you sure that jQuery is actually loading? Could you provide a link to the page that demonstrates the problem? It _looks_ like your path to jQuery is different from the path to the plugins.

Comment: yes, its actually loading.. i test them separately and isolate the problem then i found out everytime i combine those both plugin they dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jQuery .js is included before any of the plugins .js in `<head>` section.